# Solve discrete dynamical system

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to resolve the following discrete dynamical system: 
$$x_{n+1}=0.5x_n+0.2y_n+0.5z_n$$
$$y_{n+1}=0.1x_n+0.8y_n+0.1z_n$$
$$z_{n+1}=0.4x_n+0.6z_n$$
with the starting conditions:
$$x_0=12$$
$$y_0=7$$
$$z_0=1$$
solve the system for n=5 and determine the solution when $n \rightarrow \infty$

I already searched in the internet but didn't find anything useful and we never really saw it in class, so I honestly have no clue of how to solve this problem.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

These are recurrence equations.  The solution is to think that you recurrently substitute each solution to solve n steps:

STEP 1:

$x_1=0.5(12)+0.2(7)+0.5(1)$

$y_1=0.1(12)+0.8(7)+0.1(1)$

$z_1=0.4(12)+0.6(1)$

so

$x_1=6+1.4+0.5=7.9$

$y_1=1.2+5.6+0.1=6.9$

$z_1=4.8+0.6=5.4$

These values are STEP 1.

To get STEP 2, you increment $n$, you use same equations and just make $x_0=x_1$, $y_0=y_1$, $z_0=z_1$ you will get the new $x_2, y_2$ and $z_2$.  This is a recurrence.

You can use a simple spreadsheet to solve for n=5 and also for a large n to see what happens when $n$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 1):

General procedure: your system can be written in matrix form:
$$v_{n+1} = M v_n$$
with
$$v_n = \pmatrix{x_n\cr y_n\cr z_n},\qquad M=\cdots$$
So
$$v_n = M^n v_0.$$
Diagonalizing/finding the Jordan form of $M$ you can find easily the required limit.

Answer (score 0):

For the solution when $n \to \infty$, if there is a stable one you can find it by setting $x_{n+1}=x_n$ and so on.  That gives you three equations in three unknowns which you should be able to solve.  If the sum of the coefficients of the $x_{n+1}$ equation were $1$, the total of the three variables would be a constant and you would know there was a stable solution.  In this case the solution is constantly growing.

Answer (score 0):

**Discrete dynamic system**

$$
x_{n+1} = \mathbf{A} \, x_{n}
$$
with
$$
\mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{10}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 & 2 & 5 \\
 1 & 8 & 1 \\
 4 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right],
\qquad
x_{0} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 12 \\
 7 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Reduce matrix to Jordan form**

This matrix can be diagonalized:
$$
  \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{P} \, \Lambda \, \mathbf{P}^{-1} \\
$$
with
$$
\begin{align}
% P
\mathbf{P} & =
\left[
\begin{array}{lll}
 1.16782 & \phantom{-}0.340305 & -1.25813 \\
 0.811527 & -2.09823 & \phantom{-}0.0367049 \\
 1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\end{array}
\right] \\[5pt]
% L
\Lambda & =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1.06713 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0.736122 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.0967491 \\
\end{array}
\right] \\[5pt]
% Pinv
\mathbf{P}^{-1} & =
\left[
\begin{array}{lll}
 \phantom{-}0.332661 & \phantom{-}0.249064 & 0.409388 \\
 \phantom{-}0.120731 & -0.378006 & 0.16577 \\
 -0.453392 & \phantom{-}0.128942 & 0.424842 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

**Solution**

$$
 x_{5} = \mathbf{A} \left( \mathbf{A} \left( \mathbf{A} \left( \mathbf{A} \left( \mathbf{A} x_{0} \right) \right) \right) \right) = \mathbf{A}^{5} x_{0}
$$
$$
x_{5} = \mathbf{A}^{5} x_{0} =
\mathbf{P} \, \Lambda^{5}\, \mathbf{P}^{-1} x_{0}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{lll}
 2.17157 & 0.83869 & 1.44319 \\
 0.746115 & 1.79575 & 0.9095 \\
 1.02384 & 0.653539 & 2.26414 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 12 \\
 7 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
% 
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
 33.3728 \\
 22.4332 \\
 19.125 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$

**Large $n$ behaviour**

To understand the asymptotic behavior, compute
$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{A}^{n},
$
and examine $\lim_{n\to\infty} \Lambda^{n}$. Eigenvalues less than unity will disappear, and the largest eigenvalues will grow exponentially. The three eigenvalues are plotted below.

[image: 1545368]